# Against the moment

Tags: nouns, prepositions

> "What?" I queried, still drumming away at my typewriter, copying the
>   list of incendiary fires against the moment when the case should be
>   complete and the story released for publication, as it were."

I didn't find in dictionaries what "against the moment" could mean in that sentence. I guess that it means "to look forward". Am I right?

Please, if anyone can explain it to me, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. It is referring to a time in the future.

"...copying the list of incendiary fires **for the time** when the case should be complete...."

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation!